# Dompdf-Laravel not working with Unicode character

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.5 with DOMPDF its work fine for English but not working for Unicode it's always output `????` symbol to me

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;

class PdfController extends Controller
{
    public function export(){
        $data['title']="Print Report";
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);
        return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
    }
}
```

**Blade**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: khmer;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: url({{asset('fonts/khmer.ttf')}}) format('true-type');
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    កម្ពុជាក្រោម
</body>
</html>
```

Result `?????????`

Comment: Try `UTF-16` instead. Does you computed have Khmer language support?

Comment: Yes my computer have Khmer language

Comment: I try UTF-16 still not working

Comment: Improve Formatting

Answer (score 6):

you just need to add **font-family: DejaVu Sans;** in your body or also you can set the font family to any specific div in which you are going to display the Unicode Characters.

For body:
`body{font-family: DejaVu Sans;}`

And for a specific div:
`<div style="font-family: DejaVu Sans;"> --- </div>`

Hope this would help.

Comment: Why that font specifically?

Comment: @Psychemaster actually there are two other fonts (** {Arial Unicode MS,Lucida Sans Unicode}**) but they are not friendly like this one.  DejaVu Sans is a open-source font and is bundled in many Linuxes (for example, Ubuntu, OpenSUSE, Mandriva). Other fonts for showing Unicode are not open-source.
You can get the complete info regarding this from this given link 
**http://xahlee.info/js/unicode_font_comparison.html**

Answer (score 4):

@Plan-B

i use this package it works the same way as this `Dompdf-Laravel` library (`Dompdf-Laravel` library works great for other languages but not Khmer font).

- `composer require niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf`
- It has a good doc about font installation: https://mpdf.github.io/
- after installing the package, go to its repo https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf read the instruction.
- run `php artisan vendor:publish` select the library from the command prompt. You'll get the `pdf.php` in `config` directory
- Now you need to choose appropriate Khmer fonts from the doc https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/available-fonts-v6.html
- In the doc, it recommends from two Khmer font websites. You must download the fonts from the websites otherwise the fonts will not display correctly.
- download the fonts and store somewhere in the project - by default, the `config/pdf.php` choose `resources/fonts` directory 
  And here is my setup in the `pdf.php`

```php
// some code here...
'font_path' => base_path('resources/fonts/'),
  'font_data' => [
    "khmerosmoul" => [/* Khmer */
      'R' => "KhmerOSmuol.ttf",
      'useOTL' => 0xFF,
    ],
    "khmerosmoullight" => [/* Khmer */
      'R' => "KhmerOSmuollight.ttf",
      'useOTL' => 0xFF,
    ],
    "khmerosbokor" => [/* Khmer */
      'R' => "KhmerOSBokor.ttf",
      'useOTL' => 0xFF,
    ],
    "khmerosmoulpali" => [/* Khmer */
      'R' => "KhmerOSmuolpali.ttf",
      'useOTL' => 0xFF,
      'useKashida' => 75
    ]
    // ...add as many as you want.
  ]
```

Note: you might got trouble with the pdf html structure. Copy its template example form the repo and redesign it as you like.
https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf/blob/master/tests/views/exposify-expose.html

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve similar problem in my application what I've done is I've transformed view with [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) function.

In your case I would to sth like that:

```
    $data['title']="Print Report";
    $pdf = mb_convert_encoding(\View::make('pdf.invoice', $data), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
    return PDF::loadHtml($pdf)->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Also be careful with font settings. Your needs to support UTF-8 charset.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your server doesn't support your font, you need to Install a font for your server which supports your Unicode font.

To Generate A PDF, the package is using system font.